# Formula not parsing when entered in a new spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, locale, google-sheets-formula, parse-error

I have a google spreadsheet with some values and formulae in it that I want to copy into another sheet in another spreadsheet, however the pasted formulae break with `Formula parse error.` in the new sheet.

For example, the formula `=FLOOR.MATH($C$2/100*$I$5, 5)` works within the sheet in the first spreadsheet, but is broken in the sheet in the second spreadsheet, even when retyped by hand.

Removing the references and using just numbers does not change anything - still the same error. However simple formulae and references work. For example `=$C$2` and `=42/100 * 5` work in both spreadsheets as expected.

I've confirmed that the formula works on different sheets in the first spreadsheet, and with different values and cell references.

Why does this formula work only in one spreadsheet, and not when entered into a different spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. This is due to the locale difference between the spreadsheets.

The "working" spreadsheet is in a locale that uses a period as the decimal separator. The "broken" spreadsheet is in a locale that uses a comma as the decimal separator.

This means that in the formula in the second sheet, the commas separating the arguments are interpreted as decimal separators. This is why simple formulae work, and more complex ones requiring arguments fail.

This can be confirmed by going to `File -> Spreadsheet settings` and checking the `Locale` setting of each document.

To fix there are two options:

1. Change the locale of the second spreadsheet to match the first
2. Change the commas in the formula to be semicolons instead

As semicolons will work in all locales this is the preferred change that you should make, especially when first writing the formulae

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google app script, then it is possible to change the locale with the following code:

```
 // Get reference to the whole document
 var newDocument = SpreadsheetApp.create(documentName);

 // Change the locale
 newDocument.setSpreadsheetLocale('es');
```

> Where `es` is the locale for Spain